# How can I get the tfs server path for the local directory?

Tags: tfs, tfs-power-tools

I downloaded Team Server Power Tools (TFPT) to be able to take a shelveset that was created on one branch and unshelve it on another.  But for some reason, TFPT insists on asking for the target server path, which I find a bit ridiculous since it should be visible to TFPT.

A quick look around, it appears that there is an API that will state the server path, but I would rather have this available through scripting.  Is there a way to get the server path through scripting?

Answer (score -1):

If you have a shelveset called MyChanges on the Main branch in a Team Project called MyProject and you want to unshelve it to the Dev branch instead then the tfpt command would be:

tfpt.exe unshelve /migrate /source:"$/MyProject/Main" /target:"$/MyProject/Dev" "MyChanges"

Comment: Hi @rewinRR, this answer doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Sorry Adrian, I must be missing something in your question.  If you have both the source and target branches mapped in your workspace and then use the command above, it will unshelve the shelveset to your local mapping of your target branch.  You then have the opportunity to validate the pending changes before checking in the change to the target branch.

Comment: I would like it so that I don't have to specify the target server path, which should be available somewhere since the VS environment can show it.  So I'd like to script out this ridiculous requirement for having to specify the target server path.  That means I need to be able to get it from somewhere, the question is, where?